# Ground anti-static bracelet without ground wire

Tags: grounding, antistatic

I recently damaged a IC with my own static while soldering it. So I decided to buy a anti-static bracelet, but.. here where I live (Brazil) almost no building has proper grounding, only neutral and live wires are available.

I there any way around to ground myself throught the anti-static bracelet without the proper ground wire?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the same potential as your device.
So connect the bracelet to the ESD mat you're working on and on which the device is.

Do not work with mains / live wires this way.